# Operand data type char is invalid for avg operator

Tags: sql, average

I was asked to get the frequency of transactions on June 2018 using credit card ( trn_type = 'C')

My DataFrame is as follows:

```
Trn_id  ID  merchant_id trn_date    trn_amt trn_type
1   1111    33  2019-01-02  4000    C
2   1111    11  2019-01-03  200 R
3   2222    44  2018-03-25  400 P
4   2222    33  2018-03-25  20000   P
5   4444    11  2018-10-15  5000    R
6   4444    22  2018-11-13  230 R
```

Obviously the answer is going to be 0, but this was the question.
So I used the following query:

```
SELECT AVG(ISNULL(CAST(trn_type as integer),0)) as 'Frequency'
FROM Trn 
WHERE YEAR(trn_date) = '2018' and MONTH(trn_date) = '06' and trn_type = 'C'
```

And This is the answer I've gotten:

```
Frequency
NULL
```

Can anybody please help? many 10x's

Comment: Don't post images, post text instead, applies to table structures, data examples, error messages. What is the point of AVG(TRN_TYPE) when WHERE TRN_TYPE='C' ?

Comment: and what is the average value for A,C,R (your trn_type)?

Comment: I need to get the frequency of all trn_dates that occured on JUNE 2018 where the trn_type (transaction type) is 'C' which means Credit

Comment: So please update your question with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, with output as desired. Also tag it with the DBMS you use. Do you mean you want the result of the formula `number of days June 2018` / `number of credit transactions June 2018` ?

Comment: I've updated the post . Sorry for complicating things

Comment: I believe I need to get the result as 0 and not null

Answer (score 2):

Are you overcomplicating things? Frequency means how many times something occurs in the data set so if you want frequency of transaction types, this should work:

```sql
SELECT trn_type, count(trn_type) as 'Frequency' FROM Trn 
WHERE YEAR(trn_date) = '2018' and MONTH(trn_date) = '06' 
GROUP BY trn_type

--If you want percentage of 'C' relative to all records in the table:

SELECT CAST(ROUND(100. * (COUNT(trn_type)) /
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Trn ), 0) AS INT) FROM Trn 
WHERE YEAR(trn_date) = '2018' and MONTH(trn_date) = '06' and  trn_type='C'
```